# How to change a themes default editor?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that allows users to register and create posts (qaengine is the name).

My users requested I add markdown to the text editors, so I found a nice plugin that changes the text editor and allows insertion of markdown (wp-markdown). The issue is, the text editor in wp-admin has changed but the text editor on my user interface is unaffected, even though they are both interfaces for creating posts/pages etc and based on the plugin description it seems like it should apply.

Any time I google for help with this it is just about styling the text editor so I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "on my user interface"? Is this the a theme-specific admin page? If so, can you post the current code in your theme that registers the editor?

Comment: No, every text editor in wp-admin is working as I expect. But when a non admin logins to my site to interact with my blog and make posts, any posts they make use a different text editor. I'm not familiar with wordpress, where can I find that code?

Answer (score 1):

To change the text editor (TinyMCE) in the frontend of qaengine theme you need to use a child theme, create a file function.php and copy it in your child theme folder then insert this function:

```
function editor_settings($args = array()){
    $buttons = apply_filters( 'qa_editor_buttons', 'formatselect | bold italic | redo undo | removeformat | link | alignright alignjustify alignleft aligncenter | numlist bullist outdent indent | qaimage | blockquote qacode' );
    return array(
    'quicktags'     => false,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'tabindex'      => 5,
    'textarea_name' => 'post_content',
    'tinymce'   => array(
        'language'      =>'en',
        'height'                => 150,
        'toc_depth'     => '3',
        'toc_header'        => "div",
        'plugins'       => "image imagetools table wordcount searchreplace preview autolink link advlist lists directionality paste toc",
        'block_formats'     => 'Paragraph=p;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4;Pre=pre;Code=code',
        'toolbar'       => '[
                            "redo undo formatselect bold italic removeformat alignment numlist bullist outdent indent qaimage link unlink",
                            "rtl ltr table searchreplace preview blockquote qacode toc copy"
                        ]',
        'autoresize_min_height' => 150,
        'autoresize_max_height' => 400,
        'force_p_newlines'      => false,
        'statusbar'             => true,
        'directionality'    => 'ltr',
            'paste_data_images' => true,
        'setup'                 => "function(ed){
                ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                    var content = ed.getContent();
                    if(ed.isDirty() || content === '' ){
                        ed.save();
                        jQuery(ed.getElement()).blur(); // trigger change event for textarea
                    }
                });
                // We set a tabindex value to the iframe instead of the initial textarea
                ed.onInit.add(function() {
                    var editorId = ed.editorId,
                        textarea = jQuery('#'+editorId);
                    jQuery('#'+editorId+'_ifr').attr('tabindex', textarea.attr('tabindex'));
                    textarea.attr('tabindex', null);
                    });
            ed.addButton('alignment', {
                type: 'listbox',
                text: 'Alignment',
                icon: false,
                onselect: function(e) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand(this.value());
                },
                values: [
                        {icon: 'alignleft', text: 'Align left', value: 'JustifyLeft'},
                        {icon: 'alignright', text: 'Align right', value: 'JustifyRight'},
                        {icon: 'aligncenter', text: 'Align center', value: 'JustifyCenter'},
                        //{icon: 'alignjustify', text: 'Justify', value: 'JustifyFull'},
                ],
                onPostRender: function() {
                    // Select the firts item by default
                        this.value('JustifyLeft');
                }
            });
                }"
    ));
}
```

ps: some TinyMCE plugins must be installed in the TinyMCE folder in order to be able to add some desired buttons.